# Sitecore Tree list datasource - VersionExist

Tags: sitecore, treelist

in the Sitecore Treelist control, I want to get only the elements listed, which have a version on that language.

I did a search and found out that there are parameters for including/excluding items/templates. But I cant give in a condition like Versions.Count > 0

Is there a way to do it by passing a parameter to the datasource field of the template?

Or do I need to overwrite the treelist control?

Thanx

Comment: You can't do this out of the box, so you need to write your custom TreeList. You could override the method Add() and generate alert if no version exist. But why do you want to do this? If someone deletes a version of an item referenced in your field, it stays referenced and you treelist data gets "invalid". Why not checking for valid versions when querying all items in the treelist field for the presentation?

Comment: The requirement is that items which dont have versions should not be displayed in the list (I mean the left hand side list of the treelist control) Btw, you mean overriding the method Add in Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.TreeList class? Then, in which config file should I reference my new CustomTreeList Class?

Comment: @EngelbertCoder This link will get you started on creating a custom field type http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Creating%20a%20Composite%20Custom%20Field.aspx

Comment: Please have a look at @TwentyGotoTen's answer. The `Add()` method is called when the author want to add ad item to his list. This does not exactly fit your requirements, because all the items are still shown. To achieve your requirements I think you need to override the rendering of the `TreeList`. Have a look at the `OnLoad()` method, there is a `dataContext.Filter` property which takes a Sitecore query. If you can make a Query for filtering your items, this would be the way. Otherwise I think you have to override also the `TreeviewEx` WebControl (used in the `OnLoad()` of the `TreeList`).

Comment: John West also has some excellent blog posts that explain how to create a custom TreeList, this one for example: http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/community/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/06/apply-dynamic-treelist-source-parameters-with-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

Comment: ... and once you're done, it would be great to see what you came up with :-)

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work, but I didn't test it extensively...

First create a class that inherits from MasterDataView.  Note that I didn't bother explicitly getting the item in a specific language since you are only concerned with filtering based on the current context language.  If you want to be more explicit about that, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8232087/2911685

```
public class LanguageFilteringMasterDataView : MasterDataView
{
    protected override void GetChildItems(ItemCollection items, Item item)
    {
        base.GetChildItems(items, item);
        this.FilterItemsWithNoVersionInLanguage(items);
    }

    protected virtual void FilterItemsWithNoVersionInLanguage(ItemCollection items)
    {
        for (var i = items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (items[i].Versions.Count <= 0)
            {
                items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then register this class with a config include:

```
    <dataviews>
        <dataview name="LanguageFilteredMaster" assembly="sc70" type="sc70.Controls.LanguageFilteringMasterDataView" Parameters=""/>
    </dataviews>
```

Then create your custom treelist class:

```
public class LanguageFilteringTreelist : TreeList
{
    private const string DataViewName = "LanguageFilteredMaster";

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnLoad(args);
        var dataContext = this.FindDataContext();
        if (dataContext != null)
        {
            dataContext.DataViewName = DataViewName;
        }
    }

    protected virtual DataContext FindDataContext()
    {
        if (this.Controls.Count <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var child = this.Controls[0];
        return child.Controls.OfType<DataContext>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Finally, go to your Core database and register this class as a new field type.

**Update**

As noted in the comments, the above solution does not work correctly when expanding subitems.  Instead of filtering by the language of the current item version, it would filter based on the current context language of the shell. This is because the TreeviewEx control which is a child control of the TreeList control only looks at the query string for a language parameter.  If none is found it defaults to the context language.  Fortunately, we can make a very simple change to the javascript to make it also look for the hidden scLanguage field.  The file is found at \sitecore\shell\Controls\TreeviewEx\TreeviewEx.js.  Change line 63 in the onTreeGlyphClick function.

Old:

```
var contentLanguage = Sitecore.getUrlParameterValue("la");
```

New:

```
var contentLanguage = Sitecore.getUrlParameterValue("la") || $F('scLanguage');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive answer. Principally, it works, but it only checks the first level children items of the datasource root. It doesnt check the subitems (if there is only one subitem in that language, it displays all subitems) Can you offer a modification so that the children are also filtered with versions?

Comment: It works for me on subitems.  It should execute the GetChildItems method on the data view each time you expand a node.  Maybe try stepping into the code to make sure it's getting called.

Comment: Wait...  I do see a problem with subitems, but not the one you described.  I'll take another look.

Comment: Ok, I have a new-found dislike of the treelist control.  It is way too difficult to extend.  I did however find a workaround for the problem.  I will update the answer to include it.

Comment: Just to confirm, this still applies to 8.1 -3. The only difference is the javascript code. You do not need to make that change anymore as sitecore now appends selected language to html like:
`<input id="FIELD9318757_all_Language" type="hidden" value="en-CA">`

You can see newer there on sitecore's stackexchange
http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-to-filter-items-by-language-in-treelist-field