# How to Sort a TreeList in Sitecore 6 in the Source

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

My team uses **Sitecore 6** as content management system and then .Net to interface with Sitecore API. In many of our templates we make use of a **Treelist**. When adding a new item to the selected items Treelist it automatically puts the item at the *bottom of the list*.

In some lists they get very large. In most cases end users would like to see these lists sorted **descending by a Date field** that is part of the templates that can be added as selected to the Treelist.

Programmatically on the .Net side its very easy to handle this using **Linq OrderByDescending** and all displays great in the site to visitors. What I am trying to figure out is how to get it to display the same in **Sitecore Content Editor**.

I've not found anything from Google search other than there seems to be a **SortBy** you can specify in the source but I tried this and can't get it to have any effect.

Has anyone dealt with this before? Again, main goal is to sort items in a Treelist in the Sitecore Content Editor itself.

Thanks for any input anyone has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a sorted-by-name treelist in response to this question:

[How to sort the selected items in a Sitecore Treelist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462117/how-to-sort-the-selected-items-in-a-sitecore-treelist/21463608#21463608)

It works and should be easily converted to sort by date.

Unfortunately, you have to copy/paste quite a lot of Sitecore's existing code. It is also a significant customization of the product that might need to be reworked if you do an upgrade. If neither of these are problems for you, then give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I've marked Martin Davies response as answer to this, it led me down the right path, thanks Martin. I also had posted this in the Sitecore forums and got the following response. Posting here as an additional answer to help any others that might encounter same thing.

[Response to question in Sitecore Forum](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=61467)