# Sort treelistex by displayname, both available and selected items per language

Tags: sitecore, custom-fields, sitecore8, treelist

I'm working with Sitecore 8 Update 2

I'm looking for a way to sort all items ( mainly the available items ) from a treelistex by displayname per language.

I've found some way to extend the list of selected items but not for the available items ( left column ).
[How to sort the selected items in a Sitecore Treelist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462117/how-to-sort-the-selected-items-in-a-sitecore-treelist/21463608#21463608)

I've also found this but i can't seem to get it to work ( SortBy )
http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/10/more-enhancements-to-the-treelist-field-type-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

Can someone give me a clear explanation on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of achieving this could be writing a processor on Save Event Pipeline. When item save is called, you can check for TreelistEx field and Sort the selected values (since they are pipe separated guids, you may need to get each item from guid and re-arrange the pipe separated guids based on your sort) based on any field on the selection. I also think this will incur a performance hit on save (likely not much).

Comment: Does this not apply to the " selected items " instead of the " available items ". I would need to sort when the treelistex is renderd, not saved ( if i'm not mistaking )