# Get Item in all languages in which it has a version

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Say we have an Item Product(which has versions in en, jp, zh and 0 versions in ru). How can I get this item in en, jp and zh and not in ru.

I tried the below code.

```cs
Item tempItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(tempID);
foreach (var itemLanguage in tempItem.Languages)
{
  //Do Something
}
```

Here `tempItem.Languages` is returning all four languages where I was expecting only three as **ru** does not have  versions.

Is it the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to check the versioncount of the returned items. There are probably better ways to achieve this, but following your own code example, it would look something like this:

```cs
Item tempItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(tempID);
foreach (var itemLanguage in tempItem.Languages)
{
    var item = tempItem.Database.GetItem(tempItem.ID, itemLanguage);
    if (item.Versions.Count > 0)
    {
        // do something. If there is no "ru" version, this will be 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran an experiment to get a list of languages with the number of versions for items with varying numbers of children to check how expensive this is on the system.

The script below returns a list with the names of languages which have versions for the item.

```cs
public static List<string> LanguagesWithContent(this Item item)
{
    var result = ItemManager.GetContentLanguages(item).Select(lang => new {
        lang.Name,
        Versions = ItemManager.GetVersions(item, lang).Count
        //this is better than db.GetItem(item.ID, lang).Versions.Count      
    }).Where(t => t.Versions > 0).Select(t => t.Name).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

---

## Benchmarking performance

### First Load using  GetVersions - when data is not from cache

- 0.7298ms to get Version Counts with 8 language versions. Time to load item: 9.3041ms. Langs:  es-ES, es-MX, sv-SE, en, it-IT, pt-BR, fr-FR, de-DE
- 0.0448ms to get Version Counts with 7 language versions. Time to load item: 2.0039ms. Langs:  es-ES, es-MX, en, it-IT, fr-FR, de-DE, ro-RO
- 0.0334ms to get Version Counts with 6 language versions. Time to load item: 3.145ms. Langs: es-ES, es-MX, en, it-IT, fr-FR, de-DE
- 0.0307ms to get Version Counts with 5 language versions. Time to load item: 1.5976ms. Langs:  es-MX, en, it-IT, fr-FR, de-DE
- 0.0353ms to get Version Counts with 4 language versions. Time to load item: 10.2764ms. Langs: en, de-DE, ja-JP, da
- 0.0258ms to get Version Counts with 3 language versions. Time to load item: 1.9507ms. Langs:  en, de-DE, ja-JP
- 0.0193ms to get Version Counts with 2 language versions. Time to load item: 2.0533ms. Langs:  en, de-DE
- 0.0201ms to get Version Counts with 1 language versions. Time to load item: 4.7689ms. Langs:  en

### Repeat 1st Load experiment, using GetItem instead of GetVersions

conclusion: it's better to use ItemManager.GetVersions(item, lang).Count
than db.GetItem(item.ID, lang).Versions.Count to get the list of language versions an item contains.

- 3.4936ms to get Version Counts with 8 language versions. Time to load item: 8.9118ms. Langs: es-ES, es-MX, sv-SE, en, it-IT, pt-BR, fr-FR, de-DE
- 0.9966ms to get Version Counts with 7 language versions. Time to load item: 1.6489ms. Langs: es-ES, es-MX, en, it-IT, fr-FR, de-DE, ro-RO
- 1.0875ms to get Version Counts with 6 language versions. Time to load item: 3.1538ms. Langs: es-ES, es-MX, en, it-IT, fr-FR, de-DE
- 0.5891ms to get Version Counts with 5 language versions. Time to load item: 1.4402ms. Langs: es-MX, en, it-IT, fr-FR, de-DE
- 2.2096ms to get Version Counts with 4 language versions. Time to load item: 9.8701ms. Langs: en, de-DE, ja-JP, da
- 0.9255ms to get Version Counts with 3 language versions. Time to load item: 2.5175ms. Langs: en, de-DE, ja-JP
- 0.7606ms to get Version Counts with 2 language versions. Time to load item: 2.2407ms. Langs: en, de-DE
- 1.9032ms to get Version Counts with 1 language versions. Time to load item: 5.0206ms. Langs: en

  ### Subsequent loads - item is cached already

  using ItemManager.GetVersions(item, lang) in this case. GetItem should in theory give similar results since subsequent loads leverage cache.
- 0.569ms to get Version Counts with 8 language versions. Time to load item: 0.0372ms. Langs: es -ES, es-MX, sv-SE, en, it-IT, pt-BR, fr-FR, de-DE
- 0.0429ms to get Version Counts with 7 language versions. Time to load item: 0.0475ms. Langs:  es-ES, es-MX, en, it-IT, fr-FR, de-DE, ro-RO
- 0.025ms to get Version Counts with 6 language versions. Time to load item: 0.0247ms. Langs: es-ES, es-MX, en, it-IT, fr-FR, de-DE
- 0.0239ms to get Version Counts with 5 language versions. Time to load item: 0.0201ms. Langs:  es-MX, en, it-IT, fr-FR, de-DE
- 0.0342ms to get Version Counts with 4 language versions. Time to load item: 0.0216ms. Langs:  en, de-DE, ja-JP, da
- 0.0258ms to get Version Counts with 3 language versions. Time to load item: 0.0197ms. Langs:  en, de-DE, ja-JP
- 0.0228ms to get Version Counts with 2 language versions. Time to load item: 0.019ms. Langs:   en, de-DE
- 0.0228ms to get Version Counts with 1 language versions. Time to load item: 0.0178ms. Langs:  en

Comment: Are your benchmark results averages of x runs? Or did you measure each test just once? The numbers you listed look strange.

Comment: this is a snapshot of a single run, not an average. Though i did run it multiple times to check if the numbers are consistent.

Comment: It's better to iterate over db.GetLanguages() than item.GetLanguages(). They both return the same list of languages which are in use on your system (in /sitecore/system/languages) but item.GetLanguages is much slower.  I ran 100 iterations of each and db.GetLanguages() took 0.2ms while item.GetLanguages() took 387.3ms.

Don't iterate through Sitecore.Globalization.LanguageDefinitions.Definitions - it returns a full list of known language definitions (131 in my case)